# Please re-consider the suspension of my review previlege

Tags: support

It was this answer that I reviewed as 'Looks OK' but was judged as incorrectly handled.
https://superuser.com/review/first-answers/1113523

The comment pointed out that the answer was covered in the accepted answer, but MacOS 10.11 was not covered in the accepted answer.

The comment also pointed out that it is a duplicate of an existing answer among unaccepted ones, but it was very hard for me to detect when I carefully reviewed the question, the accepted answer, and the answer of interest.

So I wonder if the ban can be lifted.

Answer (score 3):

The suspension will expire on April 1st.

The answer in your review is wholly incomplete, lacks any real information on how to actually implement a solution, and provides nothing more than a link. The details from the link is literally one line of code and would have been trivial to copy here but would also benefit from explanation.

You were review suspended 7 times last year alone for various periods and I'm inclined to agree with your suspension here. More care should have be taken when reviewing.

You might want to read our help centre as it describes what we expect from questions and answer.

- [How do I ask a good question?](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask)
- [How do I write a good answer?](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-answer)
- [Why we do not accept link-only answers](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259)